# How do I fill an Angular Boostrap Table Widget with data returned from an API call?

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-5, angular-bootstrap

I am trying to make an API call and use that data I receive to use in a Bootstrap Angular Table Widget.

The widget I am using: [Complete example (Angular powered bootstrap widget)](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/table/examples#complete)

Make sure you are working with the complete example, the one with the service and pagination etc.

I tried replacing the this.countries with the response form my api call.

```
constructor(public service: CountryService) {
    this.countries$ = service.countries$;
    this.total$ = service.total$;
        this.headers = new QueryList<NgbdSortableHeader>();
}
```

Api service:

```
getusers2() {
    return this.http.get<Country[]>(this.getusersEndpoint, this.httpOptions);
}
```

This partially works, because I get the expected output in the table, but the service still uses the hard coded class COUNTRIES. So the filtering and pagination and searching doesn't work.
How can I get this to work?

The main goal is to make a skeleton table on de page, fetch the data, and when the data is fetched display the correct table with response from api.

What would be ideal is something in this way:

```
<ngbd-table-skeleton ngIf=loading></ngbd-table-skeleton>
<ngbd-table-complete ngIf=!loading [data]="countries"></ngbd-table-complete>
```

where I would set loading in OnInit to true, fetch data, set the data, set loading to false, display the correct table with working pagination, filtering and sorting.

This could be completely impossible, my Angular knowledge isn't yet on point. If this way of doing it is possible, I would love to hear from anyone with a possible solution.

Comment: This needs more code information. You said you replaced the countries$ line but didn't show what it was changed to. If I had to guess, you assigned countries$ to the HTTP service call but didn't use `async` on the observable in the template

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The key is working with the "country.service". You should change to return the value of the API, not a hardcode "COUNTRIES". futhermore you need use "pipe(map)" to work with observables

Really you should pass to the API the values of sortColumn, sortDirection, pageSize, page and searchTermsort to return only the elements necessary. In this way you should replace the function _search by some like

So the function _search becomes like

```
private _search(): Observable<SearchResult> {
    const { sortColumn, sortDirection, pageSize, page, searchTerm } =this._state;
      return this.httpClient.get(....) //<--call to your API
```

If there're a few items, you can "cache" the values and return or the cache or the call to your API that return the "whole" countries

```
countries:Country[]; //<--a variable to store the whole countries

private _search(): Observable<SearchResult> {
    const { sortColumn, sortDirection, pageSize, page, searchTerm } =
      this._state;
   
    //if "this.countries" have values, obs%= of(this.countries)
    //else obs$=the call to your API

    const obs$=this.countries?of(this.countries):
               this.httpClient.get(..).pipe(tap((res: Country[])=>{
                    this.countries=res;
               }))

    //we work with observables using "pipe"
    return obs$.pipe(
      map((res: Country[]) => {
        //you sort:
        let countries = sort(res, sortColumn, sortDirection);

        //filter
        countries = countries.filter((country) =>
          matches(country, searchTerm, this.pipe)
        );
        const total = countries.length;

        //paginate
        countries = countries.slice(
          (page - 1) * pageSize,
          (page - 1) * pageSize + pageSize
        );

        return { countries, total };
      })
    );
  }
```

See that work with observables is much close to work with an array. You "enclosed" in a pipe.map

Comment: Hello, so when I modify the this.httpClient.get() to the this.apiservice.getusers() i get tons of errors that I can not post because this stupid comment section only allows me 500 characters.
Could you show me how I can get the response from (apiservice so i have a private apiserv: APIService in the constructor)
```
  getusers2() {
    return this.http.get<Country[]>(this.getusersEndpoint, this.httpOptions);
  }
```
Could you show me how i can do that?

Comment: PS: editting the api is not in the scope of this project. way to complex because we're forced to use a SaaS (Boomi)

Comment: @QuinnFX, what is the data you received when simply subscribe to your service?. Make a `this.apiservice.getusers().subscribe(res=>console.log(res))` and **edit** your question adding the response -well, only one or two lines. The idea is that, when we have an observable use the "tap" operator to "cache" the response and use map to filter, order and paginate the response

Comment: I am not near the computer that has the project on it for the moment, but it returns a json object with two entries in it. Its actually to display users instead of countries but I didnt rename all the stuff yet. So the api call returns a Country[] with two entries in it. Fields are id, username, firstname, lastname, rank. id is integer all the rest are strings.

Comment: remember **change the interface** `Country` with the fields you received: `export interface Country{id:number,username:string,...}`

Comment: Yes thats done the interface has already been changed just not the name of some country or countries variables. Still don't get how I can get it working tho. Are you  maybe able to show a complete example of the search function with my api in it?

Comment: @QuinnFX, [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ign4wq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcountry.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapi.service.ts,src%2Findex.html). NOTE: I forgot a `(` in the code -in the part of `tap((res: Country[])=>{`. Just corrected in code. NOTE2: In api.service replace the return of(COUNTRIES) by the call to your API

Comment: I am just getting no values in the table with your code from stackblitz. When I log the output from the call: [{id": 2,"firstname": "admin","lastname": "admin","username": admin","rank": "admin"},{"id": 3,"firstname": "mod","lastname": "mod","username": mod","rank": "materiaalbeheerder"}. I replaced the apiservice with mine in the constructor.
Now I get this error: 
Property 'countries' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts(2564)
(property) CountryService.countries: Country[]