# Angular API call keeps fetching every second

Tags: angular, rxjs, bootstrap-5, angular-ui-bootstrap

I inherited some Angular/ng-boostrap code that defined a table with static data that works fine. Now we need to fetch the data from an API call so I tried to modify it as below. I used the answer from this question as a [base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75999985/how-do-i-fill-an-angular-boostrap-table-widget-with-data-returned-from-an-api-ca).

[here](https://stackblitz.com/%7E/github.com/cherfim/angular-problem) is a minimal version showcasing the problem. ([https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/cherfim/angular-problem](https://stackblitz.com/%7E/github.com/cherfim/angular-problem) if the link is not working, copy paste will work)

**executions.service.ts** where the API call is made:

```
import { Injectable, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, of, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime, delay, map, switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

interface SearchResult {
  jobs: any[];
  total: number;
}

interface State {
  page: number;
  pageSize: number;
  searchTerm: string;
  startIndex: number;
  endIndex: number;
  totalRecords: number;
}

const compare = (v1: string | number, v2: string | number) => v1 < v2 ? -1 : v1 > v2 ? 1 : 0;

/**
 * Table Data Match with Search input
 * @param  job field value fetch
 * @param term Search the value
 */
function matches(job: any, term: string, pipe: PipeTransform) {
  return true;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AdvancedService {
  fetchedJobs: any[] = [];
  fetchedJobs$: Observable<any[]>;
  private _loading$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
  private _search$ = new Subject<void>();
  private _jobs$ = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);
  private _total$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
  private _state: State = {
    page: 1,
    pageSize: 10,
    searchTerm: '',
    startIndex: 0,
    endIndex: 9,
    totalRecords: 0
  };

  constructor(private pipe: DecimalPipe,
    private http: HttpClient) {

    this.fetchedJobs$ = this.http.get<any[]>(`https://api.publicapis.org/entries`).pipe(
      tap((res: any[])=>{
        this.fetchedJobs=res;
    }));

    this._search$.pipe(
      tap(() => this._loading$.next(true)),
      debounceTime(200),
      switchMap(() => this._search()),
      delay(200),
      tap(() => this._loading$.next(false))
    ).subscribe(result => {
      this._jobs$.next(result.jobs);
      this._total$.next(result.total);
    });
    this._search$.next();
  }

  /**
   * Returns the value
   */
  get jobs$() { return this._jobs$.asObservable(); }
  get total$() { return this._total$.asObservable(); }
  get loading$() { return this._loading$.asObservable(); }
  get page() { return this._state.page; }
  get pageSize() { return this._state.pageSize; }
  get searchTerm() { return this._state.searchTerm; }

  get startIndex() { return this._state.startIndex; }
  get endIndex() { return this._state.endIndex; }
  get totalRecords() { return this._state.totalRecords; }

  /**
   * set the value
   */
  set page(page: number) { this._set({ page }); }
  set pageSize(pageSize: number) { this._set({ pageSize }); }
  set startIndex(startIndex: number) { this._set({ startIndex }); }
  set endIndex(endIndex: number) { this._set({ endIndex }); }
  set totalRecords(totalRecords: number) { this._set({ totalRecords }); }
  set searchTerm(searchTerm: string) { this._set({ searchTerm }); }

  private _set(patch: Partial<State>) {
    Object.assign(this._state, patch);
    this._search$.next();
  }

  /**
   * Search Method
   */
  private _search(): Observable<SearchResult> {
    const { pageSize, page, searchTerm } = this._state;

    return this.fetchedJobs$.pipe(
      map((res: any[]) => {

      let jobs = Object.values(res);

      // 2. filter
      jobs = jobs.filter(job => matches(job, searchTerm, this.pipe));
      const total = jobs.length;

      // 3. paginate
      this.totalRecords = jobs.length;
      this._state.startIndex = (page - 1) * this.pageSize + 1;
      this._state.endIndex = (page - 1) * this.pageSize + this.pageSize;
      if (this.endIndex > this.totalRecords) {
        this.endIndex = this.totalRecords;
      }
      jobs = jobs.slice(this._state.startIndex - 1, this._state.endIndex);

      return  { jobs, total } as SearchResult;

    }));

  }
}
```

**app.component.ts** where the subscription is done:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AdvancedService } from './executions.service';
import { CommonModule, DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  imports: [CommonModule],
  providers: [AdvancedService, DecimalPipe]
})

/**
 * Datatable Component
 */
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  tables$: Observable<any[]>;
  total$: Observable<number>;
  testbooks: any[] = [];

  constructor(public service: AdvancedService) {
    this.tables$ = service.jobs$;
    this.total$ = service.total$;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.tables$.subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log(data.length);
      this.testbooks = data;
    });
  }
}
```

then using it in the template with

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table id="datatable" class="table table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap w-100 datatables">
                        <tbody *ngFor="let job of testbooks;let i=index;">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="card">
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            <h1>test</h1>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end card body -->
        </div>
        <!-- end card -->

    </div>
    <!-- end col -->
</div>
<!-- end row -->
```

I see in the browser console that he call is made, data fetched and displayed, my problem is that the API is being called non stop and data refreshed as a result (like once a second).

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: There is a lot of code here.  It would be much easier for others to help if you created a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Also, the title of your post mentions using fetched data with ng-bootstrap, but at the end of the post you say everything is working except the data keeps refreshing.  I suggest to update your title to represent the problem you are having.

Comment: Your stackbiz is not working. It throws 404

Comment: I just tried from another not-logged-in machine and it works fine, I honestly don't know what's happening !

Comment: I got what the problem is with stackblitz, stackoverlfow is change the character '~' in the URL to '%7E' causing the 404, not sure how to fix it though :/

Comment: I added the link, copy paste should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `_search` method in `AdvancedService`, you are calling the `totalRecords` and `endIndex` setters (lines 118 and 122 in StackBlitz). These setters call the `_set` method, which `next`s the `_search$` Subject, which then causes the `_search$` stream subscription inside the service constructor to run.

I do not think you should be `next`ing the `_search$` Subject when setting `startIndex`, `endIndex` and `totalRecords`. Something like this should work:

```js
  set startIndex(startIndex: number) {
    this._set({ startIndex }, false);
  }

  set endIndex(endIndex: number) {
    this._set({ endIndex }, false);
  }

  set totalRecords(totalRecords: number) {
    this._set({ totalRecords }, false);
  }

  private _set(patch: Partial<State>, triggerSearch = true) {
    Object.assign(this._state, patch);

    if (triggerSearch) {
      this._search$.next();
    }
  }
```

Comment: you are right, when I remove this._search$.next(); call from _set method the refresh of the data stops, but then when I change the pagesize from UI it doesn't refresh because the call is not there :/ . any idea how to keep those ?

Comment: Check my updated answer for one possible solution

Comment: Even with this, it still triggers the API non-stop if I change one of those parameters. Thank you, this gives me a starting point to fix it.